# What does that javascript syntax do?

Tags: javascript, oop

what would `r` equal? and why?

In other words, how Boolean operators work with objects?

```
var data = {x:123, y:456};
var r = data && data.x || 0;
```

update:

when I run it `r` always  equals `x`, but I didn't understand why.

Comment: Value of `r` will be (`data.x` if `data` is `truthy`) or `0`

Comment: What was `r` after you tried to run this?

Comment: I've never seen this combination of `&&` and `||`.  I'd usually see this as `var r = data ? data.x : 0;` (which is less characters and *may* be less confusing).

Comment: Did  the Javascript documentation on MDN not help?

Comment: @RocketHazmat that has slightly different behavior if `123` is falsy and `0` isn't.

Comment: @JanDvorak: You mean if the object had `{x: ''}` (or something)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, that is not entirely equivalent. It would have to be `var r = data ? (data.x ? data.x : 0) : 0`

Comment: @trincot: I guess you're right.  My example wouldn't work if `x` didn't exist.

Comment: @Rayon `truthy` means not null for example?

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't know how I would frame my search :)

Comment: @Zahema truthy means it coerces to `true`, like in an `if` statement

Comment: @Zahema – [___`Truthy and Falsy Values`___](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: [mdn about "truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Really, there is documentation on the internet.

Comment: @Zahema you can test truthiness by evaluating `!!{value}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy),

> Javascript uses type coercion in Boolean contexts.

There are 8 "falsy" values in Javascript

- false
- null
- undefined
- 0
- NaN
- ''
- ""
- document.all

In your example, `data && data.x || 0`, the && and || make this a Boolean context.  `data` is coerced to a Boolean.  If it is not one of the values listed above it is coerced to true.

Programmers often check to see if an object is defined (i.e. not null and not undefined) by checking to see if the value is "falsy".  Your example could be rewritten as

```
var r = 0;
if(data && data.x){
  r = data.x;
}
```

Which I think makes it clear that you are checking to see if `data` is defined and `data.x` is not falsy (e.g. 0).  This is a common technique to avoid null reference errors if you are unsure if the variable contains a valid object or not.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the assignment, remember [JavaScript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```
var r = data && data.x || 0
```

The `&&` is operated on before the `||`, the `&&` returns the last operand if both coerce to `true`, and `false` otherwise. So, it would be reduced to this:

```
var r = data.x || 0
```

Now the `||` operator returns the first operand that returns true, and since `data.x` coerces to `true`, it would return `data.x`:

```
var r  = data.x
```

Regarding Javascript objects themselves, they will always return `true`, even if the object if empty. i.e. `obj = {}`

On the other hand, if you validate an object's property, it's a different case: if the property has the Boolean value of `false` or the numeric value of `0`, the validation will interpret both those values as `false`, as `0 == false` but `0 !== false`.

In practical terms, let's assume:
`var data = { x:false, y:456 };
var r = data && data.x || 999;`
`r` would equal `999`, the same if true if `data.x` were set to `0.